# Where can I ask about best moment to show an ad in my Android app?

Tags: discussion

I am developing an android app and I am going to implement Admob interstitial ads. I would like to ask about the best moment to show them, where, and something else... but I don't know what is the correct StackExchange community to do this. Could you recommend me one?

Comment: Wouldn't this be better on the meta.stackexchange.com site since the question is about which stackexchange site to use, and is not directed at SO specifically?

Comment: @PatrickEvans, This meta having been the old hub and the question having to do with programming in the broader sense don't make it too unwelcome here though in my estimation. Still, +1 for the likely, most correct location for the enquiry.

Comment: Oh wasn't meaning to make it seem unwelcome, since it does deal with programming. Was just meaning would probably get a better set of answers from there then here. For instance as I tend to only be on SO I do not know many of the other exchanges so I wouldn't be able to give a good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go for either [UserExperience](http://us.stackexchange.com) or [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

UX is probably the better choice as this seems to be more of a "how to best treat the user" question.

Do make sure to read their Help sections and guidelines prior to posting though to both ensure your question is on-topic and that you include all the relevant information they expect.

Comment: @AlbertoFernández, Sure thing. Hope you get some good discussion/input over there. They're a helpful bunch from the bits I've read (I'm not active there, just a lurker).

Comment: @AlbertoFernández, It might be worth editing in a link to your Question there in your Question here in case people have the urge to weigh in.